# How to insert variable length list into string

Tags: python-3.x

I have what I think is a basic question in Python:

I have a list that can be variable in length and I need to insert it into a string for later use.
Formatting is simple, I just need a comma between each name up to nameN and parenthesis surrounding the names.

```
List = ['name1', 'name2' .... 'nameN']
string = "Their Names are <(name1 ... nameN)> and they like candy.
```

Example:

```
List = ['tom', 'jerry', 'katie']
print(string)
Their Names are (tom, jerry, katie) and they like candy.
```

Any ideas on this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What about when there's only one name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Create a comma-separated string with names
the_names = ', '.join(List) # 'tom, jerry, katie'

# Interpolate it into the "main" string
string = f"Their Names are ({the_names}) and they like candy."
```

Comment: Just a heads up, OP wants the names surrounded by parens, not angle brackets (I was not the downvoter).

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to achieve that.
You could use print + format + join similar to the example from @ForceBru.
Using format would make it compatible with both Python2 and Python3.

```
names_list = ['tom', 'jerry', 'katie']

"""
Convert the list into a string with .join (in this case we are separating with commas)
"""
names_string = ', '.join(names_list)
# names_string == "tom, katie, jerry"

# Now add one string inside the other:
string = "Their Names are ({}) and they like candy.".format(names_string)
print(string)

>> Their Names are (tom, jerry, katie) and they like candy.
```